# Toggle Button to set input type hidden field

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to have a toggle button where ...

JQuery and Php needed here?

If I click it one...the input hidden will be:

```
// Display this one if $myPhpVar isset
<input type="hidden" name="myHidden" id="myHidden" value="<?php echo $myPhpVar ?>" />
```

and if I click again:

```
// Display this one if $myPhpVar is not empty
<input type="hidden" name="myHidden" id="myHidden" value="" />
```

Hope I've explaining properly.

UPDATE: What I want to do is that If $myVar is not empty when I click button X then it will set the value to blank.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="myHidden" id="myHidden" value="<?php echo isset($myPhpVar)?$myPhpVar:''; ?>" />

Comment: ps: What is the difference between "isset" and "not empty"? it is set even if it is not empty.

Comment: Why not just use a checkbox?  It will achieve the same job, and is far better from a usability and accessibility point of view.  If you want to customize the presentation of it you can then hide it with javascript and have some other item on the page toggle its state.  If the user doesn't have javascript enabled they'll just get the checkbox instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

```
var phpvar = "<? php echo $myPhpVar ?>";

$('#myButton').toggle(function() {
$('myHidden').val(phpvar);
} ,function() {
$('myHidden').val('');
});
```

and example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8dwNf/1/

Comment: My version is not working frank...Here's the JS come: <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//add functions here
 
  var phpvar = "<?php echo $myVar ?>";

  $('#myButton').toggle(function() {
  $('#myHidden').val(phpvar);
  } ,function() {
  $('#myHidden').val('');
  });

  
});
</script>

Comment: I get Syntax error T ECHO on this line: var phpvar = "<? php echo $myPhpVar ?>";

Comment: Strange , that's a php error . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171453/unbelievable-php-script-wont-echo-out-string , check that your breaking out of your php <? ?> before writing your js.